# Setting default value as empty on custom meta box when no value input?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a series of custom meta boxes configured as per the code below. Everything works fine, but when a value hasn't been entered by the user, the default value in the boxes is ". This is of course an issue as this prints out on the front end. If the default was blank nothing would be output on the front end.

Any ideas?

```
$video_url_1  = isset( $values['cf_private_meta_box_video_url_1'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['cf_private_meta_box_video_url_1'][0] ) : ”;
$video_caption_1  = isset( $values['cf_private_meta_box_video_caption_1'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['cf_private_meta_box_video_caption_1'][0] ) : ”;

<label for="cf_private_meta_box_video_url">Video URL 1</label>
<input type="text" class="widefat" name="cf_private_meta_box_video_url_1" id="cf_private_meta_box_video_url_1" value="<?php echo $video_url_1; ?>" />
<label for="cf_private_meta_box_video_caption">Video Caption 1</label>
<input type="text" class="widefat" name="cf_private_meta_box_video_caption_1" id="cf_private_meta_box_video_caption_1" value="<?php echo $video_caption_1; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the character `”`, which isn't valid PHP syntax.  PHP it interpolating that as a literal character `”`.  Change it to two single quotes, two double quotes, or null.  ie;

```
isset(...) ? esc_attr(...) : '';
```

or

```
isset(...) ? esc_attr(...) : "";
```

or

```
isset(...) ? esc_attr(...) : null;
```

All three are valid PHP syntax

Comment: Thank you CJ, that's great! I have used the single quote marks and that seems to do the trick. I was sure I had tried that, but was checking the results on an existing post which had already saved the ” as the metabox data. When checking on a new post all is now blank. Thank you!